# Data folder is not able to load images from s3 bucket for cloudimage-360

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use url from s3 bucket to load the images but it returns an empty screen on the component.

Image url: https://ishtarring.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3d-images/ishtar_0000.jpg

```
<div
      class="cloudimage-360"
      data-folder="https://ishtarring.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3d-images/ishtar_0000.jpg"
      data-filename="ishtar_{index}.jpg"
      data-amount="36"
      data-magnifier="3"
      data-full-screen
    ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `cloudimage-360`, but looking at their [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6479n17j73?fontsize=14&module=%2Findex.html), it would appear that `data-folder` should point to a **folder**, whereas your code is pointing to a specific **file**.

Also, I cannot retrieve a file named `ishtar_0001.jpg` from your path, so you should check that all 36 files exist and are publicly accessible.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't make all my images public on S3. Thanks for pointing it out. Now that It's fixed. The issue is still not resolved, do you have any ideas on how to point to a folder on s3? what do you think

Comment: When using `data-folder="https://ishtarring.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3d-images/"` and looking at the browser console, it is displaying error messages like `failed to load ishtar_1.jpg` -- I think the problem is that your images are named `ishtar_0001.jpg` but it is looking for `ishtar_1.jpg`. You'll need to rename the images.

Comment: You're right. Fixed it. Thanks a lot John